# Setting up permissions for collaborators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

My app is built in rails 3, and I'm using CanCan to handle permissions.

I want to allow my users to share their projects and collaborate with other specific users (kind of like how google docs does it).

I just want to know what the best practice for something like this would be. I have a Project model and a User model right now.

Should I create a has_many :through relationship and call the join table like Collaborators or something? So a Project belongs_to a User and has_many Users :through Collaborators?

I dont think it should be too complicated, but I haven't done a relationship like this before so any advice will help.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with a `Project` having a many-to-many relationship with `User`.

Unless you expect your permissions system to be a lot more fine-grained later, this seems like a reasonable solution to me:

Create a join table:

```
rails generate migration create_project_collaborators
```

```
class CreateProjectCollaborators < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :project_collaborators do |t|
      t.references :project
      t.references :user
    end
  end
```

def self.down
    drop_table :project_collaborators
  end
end

Add the relationship to the models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => 'project_collaborators'
end
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :project_collaborations, :join_table => 'project_collaborators'
end
```

Within your `Ability` class, you can use `User#project_collaborations` to authorize appropriately (will leave this exercise up to you!)